# Removing user mailboxes in Exchange Server

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2007, mailbox, remove

I am trying to remove several user's mailboxes in the Exchange Server.  Exchange Server is on a member server (OS: Window Server 2003).  When I try to remove the Administrator mailbox, it says this:

[image]

Note: I had to censor my windows server name where my active director resides (on another machine that has OS Win Server 2008)  What does this error mean?  Seems like a connection problem from member server to server of active directory, but I am able to ping back and forth.  How may I resolve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You are trying to Delete the builtin domain Administrator account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the user's mailbox you want to use *Disable* and not *Remove*. The *Remove* choice actually deletes the user's Active Directory user account (which won't work w/ the RID 500 Administrator account).